# How does reassigning static variables work?

Tags: c++, constructor, static-variables

Since the lifetime of a static variable is that of the program what exactly happens when you try to reassign it?

Some how in the program below, the `test.loc` ends up becoming 6 before getting destroyed eventhough the constructor is the only thing that can change that value. It is the original object itself so how does one of it's member variables change?

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
public:
   int loc = 0;

   Test()
   {
      std::cout << "Constructed!" << loc << "\n";
   }

   Test(int j)
   {
      loc = j;
      std::cout << "Constructed!" << loc << "\n";
   }

   ~Test()
   {
      std::cout << "Destroyed!" << loc << "\n";
   }
};

static Test test;


int main()
{
   // Write C++ code here

   test = Test(6);


   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Constructed!0
Constructed!6
Destroyed!6 // this is the locally constructed variable
Destroyed!6 // This is the static variable getting destroyed
```

Comment: _"eventhough the constructor is the only thing that can change that value"_ but you call the constructor again to change the value... `test = Test(6)` calls the constructor again and "reconstructs" `test`, setting the value of `loc` to 6.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 : But the memory address of test isn't the newly "constructed" Test object  rather it is still the old one. So even though the constructor is called again, that object is local and is destroyed once it exits main, whereas the static variable gets destroyed during program exit.

Comment: Assignment can also change the value, and assignment is what `test = Test(6);` is.

Comment: The compiler creates a default copy assignment operator for you, and that writes the value.

Comment: `static` is a distraction here. You'd see the same thing if you defined `Test test;` inside `main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program does not define an assignment operator (`operator=`), so the compiler creates one for you.  That assignment operator will copy the value of `loc` from the source instance of `Test` and will change the value of `loc` in the destination instance.

If you add the following to your `Test` class, you'll see what is happening:

```
Test &operator=(const Test &src) {
    std::cout << "Assigned!" << loc << "<-" << src.loc << "\n";
    // this is what the default assigment operator does:
    loc = src.loc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Some how in the program below, the test.loc ends up becoming 6 before getting destroyed eventhough the constructor is the only thing that can change that value.

But that's essentially what you're doing to change the value of `loc`. If I run your program, I get this output:

```
Constructed!0
Constructed!6
Destroyed!6
Destroyed!6
```

Two constructors and two destructors are called. The first constructor is presumably called as soon as the program enters `main`, where `test` is constructed with the constructor that takes no argument. The second constructor is called when you do `Test(6)`. This creates a new `Test` object whose `loc` is set to 6, and then the temporary is assigned to `test`. `test` is now essentially a copy of the temporary you created. As for the two destructors, one is of the temporary `Test(6)` that you've created, and one is of `test`.

Comment: "The compiler creates a default copy assignment operator for you, and that writes the value"

This helped me understand how it decides what to copy over.